# RippleView effect on view appears late android

Tags: android, button, ripple

I am using `com.andexert.library.RippleView`library from Here's [a link](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/blob/master/README.md)

Its working but not as expected . The ripple effect appears late i.e; when I click on `TextView` the Activity gets launched , then the ripple effect appears on the `TextView` of previous activity.

Also it shows error " cannot resolve method setOnRippleCompleteListener() "

xml file

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
        android:id="@+id/ripple_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        rv_centered="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <com.techmorphosis.Utils.TextViewCustomFont
        android:id="@+id/txt_lets_go"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white_text"
        android:background="@drawable/purple_button_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/lets_go"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium" />

    </com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

java file

```
rippleView.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {

           // @Override
            public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView) {
                Log.d("Sample", "Ripple completed");
            }

        });
```

Comment: show us how do you initialize `rippleView` variable

Comment: rippleView = (RippleView) findViewById(R.id.ripple_view);

Comment: I am waiting for ur reply :(

Comment: I didn't see any issue there. make sure you've imported the right packages.

Comment: compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.3' this the package i am working on

Comment: i meant the import statements in your activity class. Please check that

Comment: I found the problem . It needs the click even on the rippleview to launch the Activity , not the textview inside the rippleview. this is not I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by placing the view id's click event inside `rippleView.setOnRippleCompleteListener`

Eg :

```
rippleviewNavigation.setOnRippleCompleteListener(new RippleView.OnRippleCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(RippleView rippleView) {

if(id==R.id.txt_open){
// do stuffs here
}
}
```